# What is md-visually-hidden used for?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

In Angular Material Design, I see a md-visually-hidden in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/marcysutton/pen/OPbpKm) form the developer team.

It is used like this:

```
<button ng-click="toggleSidenav('left')" hide-gt-sm class="md-icon-button menuBtn">
  <span class="md-visually-hidden">Menu</span>
</button>
```

Is obviously hides the content, but what is the purpose of adding and hiding the text "Menu"? I guess the point is not to replace html commenting...

Comment: I guess they would want menu to be there in case the image does not load. By default its hidden and they could manipulate the js to make it visible if image doesn't load

Comment: http://codepen.io/marcysutton/pen/azpmpY

Comment: @Pratik, seems like a fair description, except I guess they do not do that in either the code that I linked or the code that JqueryKing linked. So in those examples it seems pointless?

Comment: Yup. for the examples it is. I too never understood the need for that. But then, its a tutorial. I can let that pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is used for screen readers. Some [context](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/daf680f0bc3a6e6460e5ae6894893970e684c3dc/src/components/chips/js/chipDirective.js#L25), there is a comment about a fragment that has `md-visually-hidden` class.